# What happens to old files on app upgrade?

Tags: android, installation, upgrade

I have an Android app that uses some native libraries (.so) via JNI. In the next release, I have made a lot of changes, and among other things, some native libraries are not used any more or have been renamed.

My question is whether these "deprecated" files are going to be removed when the user re-install my app?

Should I develop another procedure to take care of old files?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native libraries are part of the APK. APKs are not extracted on Android, but used as is, in archived form. Upgrades replace the whole APK, thus your old libraries will no longer be there once the update is done. You don't have to do anything special.